# Is there an easier way to navigate my terminal, ala tmux?

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

Suppose I want to look through a list of files and interactively open it through the terminal, I've been using

```
locate filename | head -n 1 | xargs xdg-open
```

or some such thing. The other option is to click on the filename that shows up using the mouse and then paste it.

Tmux let's me navigate my terminal, copy lines and incorporate them into commands. Is there a way to do this in bash or zsh, or perhaps directly in the terminal emulator?

Answer (score 1):

First put the choices in an array. Bash syntax:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a choices < <(locate filename)
```

Zsh syntax:

```
choices=("${(@f)$(locate filename)}")
```

The low-tech, but not very user-friendly way to let the user select one of the item is to use the [`select` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select).

```
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
  xdg-open "$choice"
  break
done
```

(Bash syntax; this also works in zsh but there it can be simplified.)

For a nicer interface, you can use [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html).

```
menu_args=()
for c in "${choices[@]}"; do
  menu_args+=("$c" "$c")
done
if choice=$(dialog --menu "$title" "$LINES" "$COLUMNS" "$LINES" "${menu_args[@]}"); then
  xdg-open "$choice"
fi
```

Comment: This is a cool solution! Here's my solution, which uses dmenu (in a script): `locate --all $* | dmenu | xargs xdg-open`.  It still doesn't let me navigate my console like tmux however. :(